# How to switch/disable fn-Key for multimedia Keys in KDE Plasma?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fn-key, kde-plasma-5

I'm using the latest KDE Plasma with Kubuntu on PC hardware. I have an Apple Keyboard attached. KDE automatically maps the multimedia keys to their respective icons (in/decrease loudness, mute, etc).

I want to switch to the default behaviour when pressing the F[1-12]-Keys, but couldn't find out how. I want F1 to be F1 and have the multimedia keys only working when pressing fn.

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41647/switch-fn-key-state) night at least be some kind of solution: `Fn + Numlock` offers the behavior you want.
I don't know if that works with an apple keyboard though.

Answer (score 0):

My last answer was deleted despite being the actual answer to your question. But here I will try again and hopefully do better. You need to go to the bios and look for something like "function key behavior". I have added an image to show what it can look like. There you can usually choose between "function key" and "multimedia key". The behavior you are looking for is usually called "Function key".

[image: IMG:]